# count number of services form docker-compose.yaml file without applying docker-compose up

Tags: yaml, yq

I need to count no of services in docker-compose.yaml file, i.e with out apply it, like filtering yaml file using yq or any other method in Linux.

for example my file is

```yaml
services:
  service-1:
    image: image2

  service-2:
    image: image

  service-3:
    image: image

  service-4:
    image: image
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

I want output like services count is 4 and name of each service

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of keys inside `.services` you can use

```
yq e '.services | length' docker-compose.yaml
4
```

---

The keys can be shown with

```
yq e '.services | keys' docker-compose.yaml
- service-1
- service-2
- service-3
- service-4
```

---

Since you did not provide a desired output, I'll just assume you want all the info in 1 command and output as a regular string:

```
yq e '"Total keys: " + (.services | length), (.services | keys)[]' docker-compose.yaml
```

```
Total keys: 4
service-1
service-2
service-3
service-4
```

Comment: thanks for answer and three outputs are very helpfull

Comment: yq e '.services' file.yml | wc -l